# Bind options without 'value' in JSON

Tags: javascript, angular5, primeng

I am implementing primeng multiselect with Angular5, javascript. when I am selecting option from the multiselect dropdown, I am getting all options getting selected.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="options" appendTo="body" [maxSelectedLabels]="2" [defaultLabel]="defaultLabel"></p-multiSelect>

options: Array<any> = [
    { name: "Options1", label: "Options1", type: "string", selected: true, id: 1 },
    { name: "Options2", label: "Options2", type: "number", selected: false, id: 2 },
    { name: "Options3", label: "Options3", type: "boolean", selected: false, id: 3 },
    { name: "Options6", label: "Options6", type: "number", selected: false, id: 4 },
    { name: "Options7", label: "Options7", type: "ddn", selected: false, id: 5 },
    { name: "Options8", label: "Options8", type: "date", selected: false , id: 6}
];
```

When I am using 'value' in json, the functionality is working fine. But, this is a restriction.

'MultiSelect requires a value to bind and a collection of options. There are two alternatives of how to define the options property; one way is providing a collection of SelectItem instances whereas other way is providing an array of arbitrary objects along with the optionLabel property to specify the field name of the option. SelectItem API is designed to have more control on how the options are displayed such as grouping and disabling however in most cases an arbitrary object collection will suffice. Example below demonstrates both cases.'

This is written in Primeng documents for getting started with Multiselect

I tried 'datakey' also as per documentation, but still, I am not able to get the desired result.

I want to bind options with any other key other than 'value' and then on selecting an option, it should particular and only option.